# Is 200 OK required to have response body?

Tags: rest, jax-rs

Does a `200 OK` response mandate a response body?

I know that `204` code is for a response for which there is no response body. But what semantics for 200?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [RFC 7231 6.3.1. 200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)

> Aside from responses to CONNECT, a 200 response always has a payload,
> though an origin server MAY generate a payload body of zero length. If no payload is desired, an origin server ought to send 204 (No Content) instead.